# Golang: В чем заключается смысл каналов?

Tags: golang, channels

В чем заключается та "соль" в каналах, которую так описывают в книжках и в видеороликах?

Я не говорю про случаи с использованием `select...case` - бесспорно, когда нужно выполнить несколько процессов, занимающих разное время выполнения это очень крутая фича языка.

Я имею ввиду такие случаи:

```
func compute(c chan int, value1 int, value2 int) {
    c <- value1 + value2
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)

    go compute(c, 15, 22)

    fmt.Println("Computed:", <-c)
}
```

Чего в этом случае мы добиваемся? Асинхронности тут нет - поток также блокируется и мы ждем выполнения функции - просто в другой горутине. Разве этот подход как-то улучшит производительность приложения в отличии от примера ниже?

```
func compute(value1 int, value2 int) int {
    return value1 + value2
}

func main() {
    result := compute(15, 22)
    fmt.Println("Greet response:", result)
}
```

По крайней мере с первого взгляда, во втором примере код куда понятнее.

Возможно, я еще зеленый и здесь смысл кроется в правильном распределении на железные ресурсы комьютера или в чем-то подобном.

В общем, прошу дать правильный курс.

Comment: Каналы это средства обмена сообщениями между горутинами (конкурентными нитями исполнения). Они могут быть как блокирующими, так и неблокирующими (буфер больше 0). Паттернов использования каналов - море. Но никакого отношения к ресурсам железа компьютера они не имеют.  Потому что основа конкурентности это горутины и то, каким образом их распределяет по ядрам планировщик Go.

Comment: > Don't communicate by sharing memory, share memory by communicating   (R. Pike )                                      
                                                                                                                                                             
 Вольный перевод: Не общайтесь, разделяя память; делитесь памятью, общаясь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

каждая фича языка направлена на решение проблем. решить проблему compute-а можно и вторым способом, которую вы указали. и тут возникают вопросы "а что, если..."
а что, если я хочу вызывать compute для 10 разных случаев, но печатать результат одновременно? а если кто первый ответит? а что, если хочу распараллелить вычисления? а что, если я хочу завершить действие, если один из 100500 горутин вернет ответ?

пример `<-c` просто демонстрирует как можно работать с каналами. Вместо `fmt.Println` это может быть какой-то слушатель.

чаще всего работу с каналами используют для ситуаций как:

- обычный FIFO. кто-то что-то положил, а мы потом с этим поработаем
- блокировщик. простой способ ожидания заверщения без WaitGroup. сюда же можно относить timeout-ы
- select. что раньше произойдет
- Пул воркеров. тут как раз каналы помогают раскидать вычисления к пулу воркеров, этот пример хорошо бы подошел вместо compute

```
func sqrWorker(tasks <-chan int, results chan<- int, id int) {
   for num := range tasks {
       time.Sleep(time.Millisecond) // симуляция блокировки
       results <- num * num
   }
}
```

этим этот список не заканчивается. Просто разговоры про каналы связывают с параллелизмом, конкурентным выполнением, блокировщиками, но это всего лишь инструмент позволяющий облегчить разработку. При правильном использовании все инструменты - полезны.

дополнительная [литература](https://go.dev/blog/pipelines)